# Objective-C __block keyword and thread-safety

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-blocks, cocoa-design-patterns

I'm wondering how I can make access to a `__block` qualified var thread-safe within the context of a method.

Example:

```
__block NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [dictionary setObject:@"test" forKey:@"test"];
    }];
    [someConcurrentQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Here the operation is added to a concurrent queue and the `dictionary` var will potentially be 
accessed from different threads at the same time.

Is this safe?  If not, how do I make access to `dictionary` safe?

Comment: I don't believe `__block` is necessary here because you are not changing what `dictionary` refers to, only internal properties of the object. I'm not sure about your concurrency issue, short of the obvious solution of simply using a serial queue or wrapping the unsafe operation in another block that is dispatched to a single serial queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As UIAdam said in his comment, `__block` isn't doing anything for you here; you're mutating the dictionary, not assigning to the variable. The variable will continue to point to the same dictionary forever.

In fact, `__block` may actually hurt you here, since it means the variable will not be captured by the block. If you're not using ARC, this means the dictionary will not be retained, and the block may be sending messages to a dead object soon. I'm not sure offhand whether ARC changes this. At any rate, you should leave `__block` off of this variable; if nothing else, the code more clearly expresses your intent without it.

As for your actual question, about thread-safety, this code is not safe. [According to the Thread-Safety Summary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000736-126010), the mutable collection classes are not thread-safe: you must send messages to a mutable collection from no more than one thread at a time. Synchronization would be one way; [setting the queue's max concurrent operation count](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:) to 1 would be another.

Comment: In ARC mode, `dictionary` _will_ be retained. Here is more info on this: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html (see 'Blocks' part)

Answer (score 4):

this is **not** thread safe but nothing to do with `__block` keyword because you are only read but not write to it.

the easiest way to make it thread safe is using `@synchronized` keyword

```
__block NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        @synchronized(dictionary) {
            [dictionary setObject:@"test" forKey:@"test"];
        }
    }];
    [someConcurrentQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

or you can use [NSLock](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or any types of lock

should read this for more information 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html